# How to iterate over directories and subdirectories that contain images and save them as jpegs in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write some Python code that will iterate over image files in several folders within a directory and if they have the .tif extension I need to open the file, convert it to RGB with a size of 2500 by 2500 and then save it as a jpeg.  The following code is not working.  What is the best way to do this in Python?  This keeps giving me an error that a file doesn't exist when I see the file in the folders:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('S:/DAM/Test/Approved/'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.tif'):
           img = Image.open(filename).convert('RGB')
           imageResize = img.resize((2500, 2500))
           imageResize.save(filename.jpg)
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve]. As an aside, I would recommend using pathlib for this, instead of the os module.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide the full path to open and save the images using the PIL library.

Assuming that you have a directory structure similar to:

```
.
└── scriptfolder
       -- your-script.py
       -- picture.tif
       imagefolder
           -- picture2.tif
           -- picture3.jpg
           imagefolder2
               --example.jpg
               --example2.tif
               --whatever.png
```

The following script should work if you are using a Linux machine and the script is located on a top level directory relative to the images:

```
# !/usr/bin/python3

from PIL import Image
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown = False):
   for name in files:
      if name.endswith('.tif'):
         filename = os.path.join(root, name)
         img = Image.open(filename).convert('RGB')
         imageResize = img.resize((2500,2500))
         imageResize.save(filename[:-4]+'.jpg','JPEG')
```

**EDIT**

In a Windows Machine you can the following:

1. Install a clean version of Python 3 for Windows (e.g. https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-376/)
2. Run the installer as an administrator and on the installation prompt make sure to mark adding the Python environment variable to the path and install pip.
3. Open a CMD as administrator and install the Pillow library with `pip install Pillow`
4. Open IDLE and create the following script: changing the ´path_to_images´ variable to the correct path where your images are stored.

```
from PIL import Image
import os

path_to_images = "D:\Images\Path-to-images"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_to_images, topdown = False):
   for name in files:
      if name.endswith('.tif'):
         filename = os.path.join(root, name)
         print(filename)
         img = Image.open(filename).convert('RGB')
         imageResize = img.resize((2500,2500))
         imageResize.save(filename[:-4]+"toJPEG.jpg",'JPEG')
```

5. Run the Module in IDLE with F5.

Comment: I am not using a Linux machine.  The path that contains the images and folders is on a totally different drive than where the python script is located.  How do I access the folders and images that are on a totally different drive and script?

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine to test. But if that is your case you need to change the current directory with [`os.chdir(S:/DAM/Test/Approved/)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.chdir) before entering the for loop and make sure that you are using the whole path and the filename when both trying to open and save the images. [This chapter of this book](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter8/) explains everything way much better than what I could write in some few lines and it's definitely worth a read.

Comment: Thanks @DanielOcando.  How do I use the whole path and filename if I want the code to just cycle through the images instead of hardcoding each filename in the code?

Comment: Notice that the path will be stored on the `root` variable and the filename itself will be stored on the `name` variable within the for loop of the code I shared, so that part should remain as if. You'll need to add the `os.chdir()` as I mentioned above to change the current directory to the directory where your images are located and I think you'll be good to go.

Comment: I tried this code and it creates one jpeg but then I get the OSError: -2 when it goes to the next file in the folder.  What do I need to do to fix the code?

```
import os
from PIL import Image
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('S:/DAM/Test/Approved/'):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.tif'):
            
            filename = os.path.join(root, name)
            img = Image.open(filename).convert('RGB')
            imageResize = img.resize((2500, 2500))
            imageResize.save(filename[:-4]+'.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

Comment: I tried this code and it creates one jpeg but then I get the OSError: -2 when it goes to the next file in the folder. What do I need to do to fix the code?

```
 import os from PIL import Image for root, dirs, files in os.walk('S:/DAM/Test/Approved/'): for name in files: if name.endswith('.tif'): filename = os.path.join(root, name) img = Image.open(filename).convert('RGB') imageResize = img.resize((2500, 2500)) imageResize.save(filename[:-4]+'.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

Comment: that didn't work.  I tried it but got the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "U:\Python files\image_conversion2.py", line 22, in <module>
    img = Image.open(filename)

  File "C:\Users\jphelps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2862, in open
    "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '.\\Collection Images\\5501SF_COLLECTION.tif'

Comment: I made the code above based on the particular conditions of the script being located in path relative as to where the images are located in a machine running Linux. I understand that your images are located in another drive, but you mind sharing some further details about your exact setup? OS, is this a network drive, etc.?

Comment: I added some instructions for Windows that you might find useful.

Comment: I have Anaconda installed on my machine running Windows 10.  I'm using the Spyder IDE.  The files are located on a network drive in a root folder with subfolders and inside those subfolders are the images.  I checked and I'm running Python 3.7 and Pillow 7.0.0.  Are you saying I should install the new version of Pillow to make this work?

Comment: Updating the version of PIL will be a good idea. But if you have a network drive you have to enter the correct path in a similar way to path = '"//someserver/someshare/path" and check that your user has the correct permissions to read and write files on the drive and the folder. Check the following [link](https://forum.inductiveautomation.com/t/python-to-retrieve-list-of-file-on-a-network-folder/10905).